# Payment Woocommerce Checkout Payment Targeting

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to target the element of "div#payment.woocommerce-checkout-payment".
My purpose is to change the link coloration.

```
  div#payment.woocommerce-checkout-payment a:link {
      color:blue;
  }
  div#payment.woocommerce-checkout-payment a:hover {
      color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }
```

I have tried many variations of targeting and it just doesn't seem to want to change. Am I targeting incorrectly. I have tired it without the div, with the id, with the div.

Sample Product: https://www.changedwards.com/product/the-success-lifestyle/
Site: https://www.changedwards.com/shop/checkout/

Comment: by default the payments are placed inside input tags so what exactly do you want? if you post your url that will be much easier to underhand what exactly you are doing

Comment: https://www.changedwards.com/shop/checkout/ with a sample item https://www.changedwards.com/product/the-success-lifestyle/

Comment: in your checkout page you have only What's PayPal as link and the term and condition do you want to target those links?

Comment: so I need to target the privacy and the terms and condition links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you go :

```
.checkout .woocommerce-terms-and-conditions-checkbox-text a  {
  color:blue;
 }

.checkout .woocommerce-terms-and-conditions-checkbox-text a :hover {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 }
```